# Ruby: Adding a Symbol to the input line in Terminal?

Tags: ruby, input

Is it possible to have a symbol, like a dollar sign $, appear before a the cursor on the user input line, in the terminal? Like a prompt, kind of.

For example. If you had something like:

```
puts "How much money do you want?"
gets.to_i
```

and would output in the terminal

```
How much money do you want?
$ >
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are controlling the terminal, while you are in Ruby, you can output what you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
print "$ >"
input = gets.chop
```

Since I use `print` instead of `puts` it doesn't put a newline after that.

This is kinda rudimentary, and there are certainly more advanced ways to do this (e.g. with ncurses and other libraries)

Comment: Thanks max. I'm totally just learning. I didn't understand the difference between puts and print, but I understand the newline now. Thank you for you help!